# How can I override the class Mailer on fosuser bundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with the ressetting's email of FosUser Bundle because is in txt and I would like to send an email with html form, but the template is a txt template also in the class don't use the 'text/html' option.

So my question is how can I override a internal class (Mailer) of FosUser Bundle (not a controller).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the fosuser docs

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.0/Resources/doc/emails.md

"Sending HTML mails"

Comment: Accept your own answer then! ^^